# import a python module whose location is unknown

Tags: python, linux, sed

I would like to import a function (function.py) from a given module in python (MOD.py), whose location I do not know. For it, I have performed two steps:

First step, I get the path to the directory that contains the module:

```
path = subprocess.check_output(['find', 'home/scripts','-iname','MOD.py','|','sed','s/\/MOD.py//g']).rstrip()
```

Secondly, I point at this directory to get the function from the module:

```
sys.path.insert(0,'{0}'.format(path))
from MOD import function
```

The code written is failing in the first step, particularly in the sed. Why is it not working? Is there a clearer way to do the first step? Is it necessary to do two steps, or is it possible to do it with one python instruction?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can use pipes with subprocess like that. pipes are a shell feature so at the very least you'd need to use `shell=True` (but that doesn't handle list commands well so you would want to switch to a string command too).

Comment: I would suggest properly installing the module in a known location, rather than trying to find it at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that you could not use pipe like that ! for using `pipe` you have to pass `shell=True` so instead of `check_output` use `Popen`, also your code failed in `path` argument of `find` add a `/` before home .

If the executed command returns a nonzero exit code, an exception is raised. you can use a `try-except` with `subprocess.CalledProcessError` to catch errors and getting the output created along with the exit code :

```
import subprocess

try:
    ps = subprocess.Popen(['find', '/home/scripts','-iname','MOD.py','|','sed','s/\/MOD.py//g'],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    path= ps.communicate()[0]
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
     out_bytes = e.output
     code= e.returncode
```

in addition as a more secure method i suggest don't use `shell=True` instead use tow command :

```
ps = subprocess.Popen(['find', '/home/scripts','-iname','MOD.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
path = subprocess.check_output(['sed','s/\/MOD.py//g'], stdin=ps.stdout)
```